# How to get details of the user that sent data (.emit()) to nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm experimenting on an app that is running with `nodejs`, `express` and `socket.io`

**Server Side:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('send_stuff', function(stuff){

        io.emit('log_stuff',newStuff);

    });

});

http.listen(54123, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:54123');
});
```

**Client Side:**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:12345');
socket.emit('send_stuff',stuff);
```

---

My question is How do I get the details of the client (ip,user-agent,etc.) that executed `socket.emit('send_stuff',stuff)`?

I want to pass it to the `newStuff` variable.

`socket.on('send_stuff', function(stuff){});` in this line `stuff` only returns the value that was send by client `emit()`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get client's ip and user-agent in `connection` event.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("ip: "+socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);
  console.log("user-agent: "+socket.request.headers['user-agent']);
})
```

Documentation can give you some hints http://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var userAgent = socket.handshake.headers["user-agent"];
    console.log("User-Agent: " + userAgent);
});
```