# Check which browser type user is using in a socket connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Am using node js and socket io. I would like to know which browser a user is using when he or she is connected.

By using

```
sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var ip_address = socket.conn..remoteAddress;  //this fetches the ip address
    var userbrowser = socket.conn. //am stuck here


});
```

How do i fetch the type o browser a user is using in the socket

I have checked on `console.log(socket.conn)`  but i cant see any helpful browser key

Comment: what do you mean by " which browser a user is using when he or she is connected" it seems a lil bit off to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get details of the user that sent data (.emit()) to nodejs server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322905/how-to-get-details-of-the-user-that-sent-data-emit-to-nodejs-server)

Comment: you mean browser is the server side and client side maybe?

Comment: by browser i mean the client side

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it:

```
console.log("user-agent: "+socket.request.headers['user-agent']);
```

Answer (score 0):

under your socket connection event you need to do this

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log(socket.request.headers)
   })
   //prints following info like 
{
  "host": "192.168.1.77:4000",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "origin": "null",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "cookie": "io=_ffsFAYurGTLZunDAAAA"
}
```